# Form with a question that asks if multilpe criteria are met

Tags: forms

In a form, I want to ask whether certain criteria are met and get a yes/no response.

i.e.

```
Do you fit into any of the following categories:
 * sporty
 * fit
 * healthy
yes/no
```

This isn't the best example, but really I'm asking someone for a yes/no response to whether they fit into one or more items in a list of categories.

Is there a good way to do this, or am I asking the wrong question in the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such scenarios, users will expect to be able to select the relevant categories.

When you are expecting multiple options to be selected then consider using check-boxes. What if some users think that **'I'm fit and healthy but not sporty'**? Or **I'm fit, sporty and healthy but I cannot select them all.**

**I will suggest you use check-boxes so the users can select multiple options if they fit into it.**

Comment: Thanks @Dipak.  I'm not really wanting to record which categories they fit into.  I only care about whether they fit into one or more of the listed categories.  Or are you saying people will expect to be able to select the relevant categories, and what I do with that information is up to me?

Comment: @NickCook Correct! We should let users select the relevant categories. Your question asks if they fit into **any of the following** - What if majority of your users fit into all? You surely need to do research for it, but asking users to select a category will be more satisfying, it might give them a sense of pride as well.

Comment: "I'm not really wanting to record which categories they fit into. I only care about whether they fit into one or more of the listed categories." 

Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: To prevent users from having to think more than necessary about what categories they fit into, you could additionally make the form disable the other categories when any one is selected, and add text at the bottom saying "Thanks; all we wanted to know is whether you fit in at least one of the categories." So for example the user thinks "I'm not sporty", then they think "I am fit" and check "fit", and before they have to think about whether they are healthy the user is told that they can move on to the next question.

Comment: @Stacked to elaborate, if a user does fit into one of the categories, they're flagged in our backend, but there's no business requirement to understand why they're flagged.